# Plot continuous line using 'dashes' argument in matplotlib's plot()

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm plotting several lines within a `for` block and I set the style of each line using matplotlib's [dashes](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/dash_control.html) argument.

One (or more) of those lines needs to be continuous. I've found no way to draw such a line other than making a single extremely long dash, as seen in the MCVE below. This works, but feels rather hackish.

Is there a more "correct" way to achieve this?

(I know I can just use `plt.plot()` with no `dashes`argument to produce a continuous plot, but I need to produce a lot of custom styled lines, mixed with one or more continuos lines)

---

MCVE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


col = ['c', 'm', 'g', 'y', 'k']
c_dash = [[8, 4], [8, 4, 2, 4], [2, 2], [8, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4], [1000, 1]]

for i in range(5):
    x, y = range(10), np.random.uniform(0., 10., 10)
    plt.plot(x, y, color=col[i], dashes=c_dash[i])

plt.savefig('test.png', dpi=300)
```

[image]

Comment: Is all you mean `plt.plot(x, y, '-')`?

Comment: Basically, yes. If you try it, you'll see the `dashes` argument does not accept `'-'`.

Comment: Still kind of hacky, but substituting 1000 with `np.inf` seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your c_dash list to include an offset param **(** offset,**(** on,off sequence **) )** you can then use linestyle as your kwarg instead of dashes. This will allow you to use the linestyle keywords `‘solid’ | ‘dashed’, ‘dashdot’, ‘dotted’` in addition to your custom dashes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


col = ['c', 'm', 'g', 'y', 'k']
c_dash = [[0,[8, 4]], [0,[8, 4, 2, 4]], 'solid', [0,[8, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4]], 'solid']


for i in range(5):
    x, y = range(10), np.random.uniform(0., 10., 10)
    plt.plot(x, y, color=col[i], linestyle=c_dash[i])
```

[image]

Comment: That's a nice answer, I wasn't aware of the `offset` param. Thanks BHawk!